# Is there a way to pre-define directories for SASS to watch?

Tags: css, sass

I have recently started using SASS in my web development. Thus far, I've found it to be a very useful utility, however I have run into a minor usibility issue.

This website I am working on has SASS files in multiple locations, for example in `/css` as well as in `/blog/css`.

Currently, to keep sass watching both directories, I need to create two different terminal tabs and run `sass --watch css/:css/` on one, and `sass --watch blog/css/:blog/css/` on the other.

It would be awesome if I could make a file or something of the following format:

```
css/:css/
blog/css/:blog/css/
```

And then just pass this config file to sass and have it watch both locations. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have your CSS files scattered like that?  Having your blog's CSS in `/css/blog/` seems like the perfect solution for your situation.

Comment: That doesn't quite keep the components of the site separate like I want them to.

Comment: @finiteloop I have flattened the hierarchy of the components of my site, i.e. one simple "css" directory for all components, etc., and I must say it's quite liberating. [See here](https://github.com/simevidas/ecmazing-site).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yeah that looks great, actually. But in this case, I'm building the blog portion as a stand alone tool, so it makes sense for me to have some stuff isolated within that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) to run multiple processes:

```
gem install foreman
```

Create a `Procfile` in the root directory and add something along these lines:

```
sass:  sass --watch css/:css/
sass: sass --watch blog/css/:blog/css/
```

To start both use:

```
foreman start
```

Comment: Works for me. I will keep this question open to see if others have any, perhaps natively supported input.