# Compiling Compass css files into different directories?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a sass/compass project. For the most part, the default setup is working.  I have a sass folder and css folder at the same level in the site, so my main scss file compiles into `/css`, great.  However, I need to create a separate scss file that I'd like to compile into `/css/themes/blogs` instead of the default `/css` folder.  Not sure how to do this, or if it's practical.

Can you configure compile locations on a per-file basis and, if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166339/is-there-a-way-to-pre-define-directories-for-sass-to-watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your blog sass files in `/sass/themes/blogs/` and watch from `/`.  As long as your files aren't prefixed with an `_` they'll be generated in the corresponding location in the css directory (`/css/themes/blogs/`).

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware it would maintain the hierarchy.